# Problem with network between windows and ubuntu ( DHCP doesn't work but static ip works)

Tags: debian, networking, windows, dhcp

So I got some ram from a friend and thought that I should install ubuntu on my old machine. So I installed ubuntu 16.04 on it and soon after this I decided that I want to make a file server out of this. So I asked a friend for a crossover cable.

I configured windows to have a static ip4 address and ubuntu to use dhcp and it worked for a time and I even got windows to share the internet connection.

Until I restarted the windows machine, thats where the problem started. Now I am search for the problem since 2 hours I tried various settings but nothing worked so far.

I changed the IP adress of the windows "server" but it didn't work.

It only works with a static ip adress on both the windows and ubuntu machine. Then the samba fileserver also works.

But I really want to get it working with DHCP.

Does anyone know what my problem could be?

Comment: About the closing votes: However it is not exactly well written, I found the question quite clear, wether it is off-topic or not is another story.

Comment: have you setup a DHCP server on windows ? if no, either set one up, or use 2 static IP.

Comment: I would feel this a SU question, but having both Linux and windows, I'll leave open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DHCP does not works magically; you need to setup a DHCP server in one of them if both of them are connected with a crossover cable; however connecting it back to the network you will have a rogue DHCP server (there can only be one DHCP server in one network).

Thus, the best solution is using static IP addresses.

The machines might have assumed automatic IP addresses the first time you connected them (169.x); automatic IP addresses might and won't be the same each time you reboot them, they are random. As again, the static IP addresses are a cleaner solution.

The ideal solution is to get a small switch, and connect them to the same network.

Comment: Oh interresting I thought dhcp just works when you setup a pc with a static ip adress and one with DHCP. Thanks for pointing that out for me.